# Apache redirects: do not redirect if URL contains

Tags: apache

i have a situation where i want to prevent any redirects if the URL contains "akamai"

Basically, if URL contains akamai do not redirect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your current redirect rules

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not very clear.

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)(?<!akamai)$ /akamai-$1 [L,NC]
```

Negative lookbehind (?akamai.